# Craft 2: Suspend user results in "Unauthorized You don’t have the proper credentials to access this page."

Tags: permissions

This pertains to a Craft v2.9.2 installation.

User X is an admin user. So she has permission for pretty much everything, except accessing site settings, etc.
For an unknown reason, User X is unable to suspend other users.
User X has all permissions assignable under `General` and `Users` on the `Permissions` tab.

Yet when she tries to suspend another user, Craft returns the following error:

```
Unauthorized
You don’t have the proper credentials to access this page.
```

I have no idea why. Is there something I am over-looking regarding what's required for a user to suspect another user?

Is there a way to find out what is causing this issue? Such as a log of such issues?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is she trying to suspend another user who's an admin user?

I just tested this and your scenario would happen if she's trying to suspend an Admin's account.

A user who's has Admin privileges can only suspend another Admin otherwise you'd have users with lower-level permissions overriding those with higher level ones.

In Craft 3, you get a more clear message if this happens:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of that. This is a new client, whose Craft installation I helping them with. I didn't realise quite so many users had full Admin level privileges. It turns out the user they were trying to suspect is one with full Admin rights. Problem solved.

Comment: @inspirednz - Nice, glad you got it fixed... easy fix. Now you get to tell people they don't need full admin... now that's a different conversation!